# Integrate Taylor expansion beyond its convergence radius

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, approximate-integration

Suppose a function $f(x)$ that has a radius of convergence $r_0$ and we want to calculate the integral
$$
\int_{-(r_0+\epsilon_1)}^{-(r_0+\epsilon_2)} f(x)\,dx \;
$$
with $\epsilon_1\ll r_0$ and $\epsilon_2\ll r_0$.
Now we use the Taylor expansion of $f$ (e.g. because $f(x)$ is not analytically integrable) and perform the integration of this second order approximation.
I think the approximation of the integral should be much better when choosing the second order Taylor approximation of the integrand than only the zeroth order approximation. On the other side the integration goes beyond the radius of converge. Are there any arguments clarifying which approximation (0th or 2nd order) is better? Currently I would just make the vague (and not that helpful) statement that using the second order approximation is better only if $\epsilon_i$ is very small and otherwise it is better to rely on the 0th order approximation of the integrand.

The background to this question is a numerical integration where I have equidistant intervals that cannot be changed (I have to cope with the given intervals). The integrand is expanded at the center of each interval. Furthermore, I have checked that in some cases the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of the integrand is exceeded when coming close to the boundaries of the interval we are currently considering. Now I have the two options to just take the zeroth order approximation of the integrand for the whole interval or to take the second order approximation of the integrand. The following picture shows an example of the Taylor expansion (0., 1., 2., 10. and 100. order) of the integrand $1/(a+(x-b)^2)$ at the origin with a radius of convergence $r_0=3$. The dark blue curve is the exact integrand. The above described problem then occurs for example if we want to obtain the approximate integral over the interval $[-3.1,3.1]$.
[image]

Comment: What is your actual example here? $f(x) = \frac{1}{a+(x-b)^2}$, but what is $a,b$?

Comment: If you are outside the convergence radius then it does not make sense to use that expression. However if the function is well behaved (i.e. no singularities) then you can Taylor expand about a different point! E.g. $\frac{1}{1+x^2} = 1 - x^2 + x^4 + \ldots$ has convergence radius $1$, however the left hand side function exists for $|x|>1$. If you want to integrate it over say $[1,1.1]$ then using the Taylor series about $x=0$ does not make sense, however the Taylor series about $x=1$ does converge here, $f(x) = \frac{1 - (x-1) + (x-1)^2/2 + \ldots}{2}$, and can be used.

Comment: @Winther: The example actually is $$\frac{1}{ (x-3\cos(30°))^2 + (3\sin(30°))^2} \;.$$
Of course it would be nice to use the Taylor expansion at a different point but in my case that is unfortunately not possible. I am dealing with a large scientific code where the current implementation  in that case is simply using a zeroth order approximation. However, I implemented the second order approximation and now I'm agonizing about whether this is a good idea because of possibly being beyond the radius of convergence.

Comment: If some series approximation does not converge in some region then why should the zero'th approximation be any good compared to the second order one? Neither would normally be any good.

Comment: Well, as you can see in the example plot the "divergence" of the Taylor series outside the radius of convergence gets worse when going to higher orders. Thus, higher orders do represent the function we want to approximate even less than lower orders (although the lower orders provide only a very rough estimation of the function, for sure).

Comment: This is one example, but I'm sure one can construct an example where the $2$'th order would be better than the $0$'th order is some regime. Unless you have some knowledge about the function you are working with that dictates that some approximation or an other should be fine then you are on really sketchy grounds by using a series approximation (of any order) outside the convergence radius. It's not a sensible way to approximate functions.

Comment: That is completely true. Therefore I asked this question here whether there is maybe some criterion which approximation is best in that case. Is outside the radius of convergence maybe always the lowest order the most sensible approximation  (that would be already a helpful statement)? It is true, for sure, that no order of a Taylor polynomial is a good approximation outside $r_0$ at all, but despite that, which is the best (the least poor ;) )? Is there any theorem about that?